# How to change the position of ion-avatar of item in ionic2

Tags: css, sass, ionic2, ionic3

How can I change the position of ion-avatar to the top of list

For example this is my code and result:

```
<ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item style="border-bottom: 1px solid #EAECEE; margin">
        <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="imgs/sender.png">
        </ion-avatar>
        <p style="white-space: initial; color:black;">
            XXXX
        </p>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
       <!--Codes-->
    </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

[image]

**& This picture what I want (if possible)**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with just css like this:

```
your-page {

  ion-item.item.item-block.item-ios,
  ion-item.item.item-block.item-md {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start; // <---- This does the trick!
  }

}
```

Let me know if that rule gets overridden because of the preference, so we can fix it.

Comment: Glad to hear that @AliH :)